# Sending form data to another websites form

Tags: wordpress, forms

I am trying to incorporate a reservation widget within my wordpress install and I have everything working fine except sending the data or it not populating on the other sites form.  The site I am trying to send data to is an online reservation software: http://www.directinn.com/demo/

Here is how I am doing my form:

```
<form name="bookingform" action="http://www.directinn.com/demo" method="get" target="_blank">       

  <input type="text" name="date1" id="Text1" class="ftxt MyDate three columns" maxlength="10" value="" placeholder="Arrival Date"/>

  <input type="text" name="date2" id="Text2" class="ftxt MyDate three columns" maxlength="10"  value="" placeholder="Departure Date" />

  <input type="submit" name="bookingformsubmit" class="book-now" value="Book Now">

  <input type="hidden" name="arrivalDay" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="arrivalMonth" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="arrivalYear" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="departureDay" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="departureMonth" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="departureYear" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="numAdults" value="1" />
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated ;)

Comment: The directinn site needs to be setup to receive your form data.

Comment: http://www.directinn.com/iframeexample.html

It says all you need to do is add the link to your form??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So they are saying if you can iFrame in their Form on your page and if you add the USERNAME for example to the URL, your USERNAME will appear on the invoice. Like this I believe:

```
http://www.directinn.com/iframefull.html/BOB
```

I do not think you can make your own form and POST to their page. I see no indication that that is possible from the link you posted of the example.

Comment: Ahh lame, thanks so much! It through me when they said use the url and username in your form..  Maybe I can suggest this to them and they can support this in the future

Comment: No problem, mark this as the answer if you believe it is the most correct.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have will submit a load of Query String data to the receiving site.

The target site may implement some type of cross-site posting prevention which is causing the blockage - or they may ignore your query string parameters entirely.

Comment: Ohh, so I thought that if I used put the url in the action of the form and get as the method, then as long as my input names matched there names it would work?  Sorry I'm still getting into forms a bit and have only successfully sued this one other time in the past but not with directinn.com